# Duplicated text in sifr

Tags: sifr

I'm having problems with sifr showing the replaced text and the flash rendered text. All the css files are loading correctly, however I'm implementing this in sharepoint 2007 so it's possible something else is causing the problem. This is the browser output I'm getting:-

h1 class="large sIFR-replaced" style="">
object id="sIFR_replacement_0" class="sIFR-flash" height="61" width="1238" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="sIFR_replacement_0" data="/Style Library/sifr/cartonnage-alternate.swf" style="">
/object>
span id="sIFR_replacement_0_alternate" class="sIFR-alternate">hello hub
/h1>

(I've removed the < down the left hand side of the above code so it displays on stack overflow)

The  is not hiding and for the life of me I can't see why - if it's somthing obvious I apologise!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS to hide the `.sIFR-alternate` text doesn't seem to be applied. Inspect the page with Firebug and see if that's the case or if the CSS is conflicting with something else.